# .map() function displays my hidden animated view for each child in React Native. And I am using keys and id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a hidden animated view that displays when you click on the specific account name. Currently, when you click an account name, the animated hidden view displays for all the children in the .map() function. I tried adding the key and id to the animated view as well but that does not work either. Still shows the hidden animated view for all the children in the map.

````
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
              {accounts.map(account => (
                <View key={account.id} id={account.id}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      backgroundColor: colors.primary,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      padding: 10,
                      marginBottom: 10,
                      marginTop: 10,
                      zIndex: 1,
                    }}>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                      }}>
                      <Text
                        onPress={() => setHidden(!hidden)}
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 30,
                          textAlign: 'left',
                          flex: 1,
                          marginTop: 'auto',
                          marginBottom: 'auto',
                        }}>
                        {account.name}
                      </Text>

                      <View>
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            fontSize: 30,
                            textAlign: 'right',
                            flex: 1,
                            marginBottom: 10,
                          }}>
                          {account.amount}
                        </Text>
                        <View
                          style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                          }}>
                          <DeleteAccount account={account.name} />
                          <Icon name="wrench" size={25} color="#000000" />
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  {hidden ? (
                    <Animated.View
                      key={account.id}
                      id={account.id}
                      style={[
                        styles.subView,
                        {transform: [{translateY: bounceValue}]},
                      ]}>
                      <Text>{account.name}</Text>
                    </Animated.View>
                  ) : null}
                </View>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>```
````

Comment: Where did you declare `bounceValue`?

Comment: It is above this code, which shouldn't matter for the question. @LeriGogsadze

Comment: I think it might be a problem. You declared it globally as I guess, that's why its value is the same for every View. Move it inside map.

Comment: I want the bounceValue to be the same for every item in the map. Whats happenening is the <Animated.View> is showing for every item in the map when I only want it to show for 1 item in the map that was clicked.